# Twilio API requests taking too long to respond when sent using Twilio Java Helper Library

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

We are using Twilio Task Router for a call routing functionality in our web project (Java 8 application running on Tomcat 9). We are using Twilio Java SDK (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twilio.sdk/twilio/7.36.2) for making Twilio API requests. When we were testing our application, it was found that Twilio is taking loo long to respond for almost every API requests sent within a time span of 1 hour. The response time is as higher as 10 minutes for a few sample requests analyzed.

The log traces for one such request is provided below. In this log trace it is found that the 10 minute delay happened after executing the line that says '`Connection request: [route: {s}->https://taskrouter.twilio.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 10 of 10; total allocated: 10 of 20]`'. As per our analysis, this trace comes from the Apache HttpClient library which is part of the Twilio SDK. The next trace : '`Connection leased: [id: 3492][route: {s}->https://taskrouter.twilio.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 10 of 10; total allocated: 10 of 20]`' that comes after 10 minutes is also from the Apache HttpClient. As per the http-outgoing trace in the below log, Twilio-Request-Duration is only 27 milliseconds. Hence we assume the delay of 10 minutes happened within the SDK and not from the Twilio Server. Please help us resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:31:22.688 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | TwilioCommandExecutor:38 | Executing Twilio command
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:31:22.688 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | RequestAddCookies:123 | CookieSpec selected: default
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:31:23.756 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | RequestAuthCache:77 | Auth cache not set in the context
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:31:23.772 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:265 | Connection request: [route: {s}->https://taskrouter.twilio.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 10 of 10; total allocated: 10 of 20]
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.018 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:309 | Connection leased: [id: 3492][route: {s}->https://taskrouter.twilio.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 10 of 10; total allocated: 10 of 20]
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.020 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:88 | http-outgoing-3492: set socket timeout to 0
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.020 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:88 | http-outgoing-3492: set socket timeout to 30500
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.020 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | MainClientExec:256 | Executing request POST /v1/Workspaces/WSd9f51d1692a76faa3079514c2a89197c/Workers/WK9cacec1e7285f98519152316bac03de8 HTTP/1.1
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.021 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | MainClientExec:267 | Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.021 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | headers:133 | http-outgoing-3492 >> POST /v1/Workspaces/WSd9f51d1692a76faa3079514c2a89197c/Workers/WK9cacec1e7285f98519152316bac03de8 HTTP/1.1
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.096 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | wire:73 | http-outgoing-3492 << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.105 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | wire:73 | http-outgoing-3492 << "Date: Tue, 09 Jul 2019 14:41:39 GMT[\r][\n]"
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.106 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | wire:73 | http-outgoing-3492 << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.106 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | wire:73 | http-outgoing-3492 << "Content-Length: 1891[\r][\n]"
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.106 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | wire:73 | http-outgoing-3492 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.131 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | headers:125 | http-outgoing-3492 << Twilio-Request-Duration: 0.027
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.133 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | MainClientExec:285 | Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.134 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:341 | Connection [id: 3492][route: {s}->https://taskrouter.twilio.com:443] can be kept alive indefinitely
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.137 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | DefaultManagedHttpClientConnection:88 | http-outgoing-3492: set socket timeout to 0
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.424 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager:348 | Connection released: [id: 3492][route: {s}->https://taskrouter.twilio.com:443][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 10 of 10; total allocated: 10 of 20]
| DEBUG | 2019-07-09 10:41:39.424 | https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-342 | TwilioCommandExecutor:40 | Twilio command executed successfully
```

Comment: The 10 minute difference comes between requesting a connection from the pool of managed HTTP connections and receiving the lease on that connection. Was your application making a lot of requests at the time that tied up all the available connections? Are you doing other things with the API at the same time? Are there other requests that don't take 10 minutes?

Comment: In a duration of 15 minutes around 25,000 API requests were made. We are calling multiple Twilio APIs on Task, Workflow, Worker and Queue resources. On an average the requests take 2-3 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

According to your comment you made around 25,000 API requests in 15 minutes. That is approximately 27 requests per second. Twilio itself has a limit of 100 concurrent connections but the Twilio Java library has a pool of 20 HTTP connection objects. If you are throwing all 25,000  requests at the library in one turn, then it is going to start with the first 20 requests using the pool, and make them. Once each request frees up a connection the next request will be made. Ultimately this means that the last of the 25,000 requests will have to wait for the previous 24,999 to take place, causing your 10 minute delay.

If the size of the connection pool isn't big enough for you, you can provide your own HTTPClient to the library. You can see the existing implementation of the [`NetworkHTTPClient`](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/twilio/http/NetworkHttpClient.java) which is likely a good model to base your own implementation on. The [connection pool limits are implemented here](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/twilio/http/NetworkHttpClient.java#L58-L60). Note that making a connection pool larger than 100 will result in API errors for higher than allowed concurrent use. If you need to consider higher API limits, I recommend you [talk to Twilio sales](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales) about your needs.

Alternatively, you could consider whether that many requests are desirable in such a short time. If it is possible to batch the requests differently and make calls at different times, you could avoid this level of queueing of requests.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation and solution. Is it ok if we modify Twilio SDK source code (https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java) for increasing connection pool size and use it in our project? I mean any license violation is there by doing so?

Comment: The licence allows for modification, but you will have to do work to keep your fork up to date with the latest in the upstream. There is likely a better way though. Like I mention in the answer, you can provide your own HTTP client to the library. This means you can subclass the `NetworkHTTPClient`, update the pool size yourself, and provide that to the library instead. I'd recommend that approach.

Comment: Yes..that's a better approach. Thanks a lot.